# how to hide and unhide worksheet using data entry from userform

Tags: excel

I don't know why am getting out of range subscript error. When I click on combobox1 and select an item, MaternityForm combobox is populated with worksheets in my workbook. Then I want to hide other worksheets apart from the one selected in MaternityForm. The active sheet will then receive data from userform but I am getting subscript out of range error..

```
    Private Sub Get_Data_Click()
           Dim ws As Worksheet
           Dim xWs As Worksheet

           For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
              xWs.Visible = True
           Next

           Set ws = Worksheets(MaternityForm.Value)
           Sheets(MaternityForm.Value).Activate
           On Error Resume Next

           For Each ws In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
               if ws.Name <> MaternityForm.Value Then
                  ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
               End If
           Next

           With Sheets(MaternityForm.Value)
             .Range("B3").Value = Me.NameBox.Text
             .Range("f3").Value = Me.PaynoBox.Text
             .Range("B6").Value = Me.DTPicker1.Value
             .Range("B7").Value = Me.DTPicker2.Value
             .Range("B17").Value = Me.FirstPayBox.Value
             .Range("B18").Value = Me.SecondPayBox.Value
             .Range("B25").Value = Me.MonthlyPayBox.Value
            .Range("H7").Value = Me.DTPicker3.Value
         End With

   End Sub
```

Comment: Unless you have a particular situation. It’s better to use ThisWorkbook, instead ActiveWorkbook. In what line you receive the error?

Comment: @Ricardo thanks i used your advice and it made my code better. The problem was that i had used a wrong worksheet name as well. Just realised that as i was following your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing your variables `ws` and `xWs`.

---

`ws` is referring to a specific sheet while `xWs` is your variable worksheet.
Therefore, your second loop is invalid (This is like saying `For Each Sheet1 in Worksheets`).

You need to loop through your **variable worksheets** and compare them to your **specific sheet**

```
   For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
       if xWs.Name <> ws.Name Then
          xWs.Visible = xlSheetHidden
       End If
   Next
```

---

With that being said, there is no need to loop twice.

Note that `ws.Name = MaterityForm.Value` will return either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. The result of this determines `ws.Visible = TRUE/FALSE`

```
Private Sub Get_Data_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.Visible = ws.Name = MaternityForm.Value
Next ws

With Sheets(MaternityForm.Value)
    .Range("B3").Value = Me.NameBox.Text
    .Range("f3").Value = Me.PaynoBox.Text
    .Range("B6").Value = Me.DTPicker1.Value
    .Range("B7").Value = Me.DTPicker2.Value
    .Range("B17").Value = Me.FirstPayBox.Value
    .Range("B18").Value = Me.SecondPayBox.Value
    .Range("B25").Value = Me.MonthlyPayBox.Value
    .Range("H7").Value = Me.DTPicker3.Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: appreciated your help. now i am clear about using the right construction. Also i was using the wrong worksheet name in my comparison but problem now solved.

Comment: For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ' Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> MaternityForm.Value Then
            ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        End If
    Next